# How do I return a specific link address using IMPORTXML and XPath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example 1. **//a/@href** - This selects the value of the href attribute from all the a elements in the document and returns the link address.

Example 2. **//a[contains(@href, 'scrapy.org')]** - This selects the **a** elements pointing to https://scrapy.org and returns the ancour text.

Is there a way to select specific links like in example 2, but return the link address like in example 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 //a[contains(@href, 'scrapy.org')]/@href
```

Comment: More directly, `//a/@href[contains(., 'scrapy.org']` doesn't involve selecting the attribute twice.